# Generating redistributable map images without a server

Tags: javascript, openlayers, client-side, openstreetmap, mapbox

I want to make an app that allows users to download static images of maps and redistribute them in Anki flashcard decks. However, I'm having a tough time figuring out how to generate the map images without facing any licencing restrictions or running my own server. I want my app to be all client side JavaScript which rules out one of the solutions I've found so far. I've seen a way to use openlayers to [export images from the canvas](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html), however a proxy sever is required to convert the canvas to a dataURL so it can be saved.

The most promising option I've found so far is the MapQuest [Open Static Maps API](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2011/05/11/get-creative-with-the-open-static-maps-api/). However, I can't find much information about how open it really is. The OSM data is open, but I'm not sure about the images themselves, as they say copyright mapquest on them. Mapbox also has a static map API with licensing restrictions that are unclear to me.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://mapbox.github.io/leaflet-image/ (but it's still very beta, I guess).

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use mapbox because of this line in their TOS: "Devices — phones, tablets, computers — may cache an unlimited amount of map imagery for offline use or to improve performance. You may not proxy or redistribute cached content."

Comment: Hm, basically, leaflet-image can also create images of non-mapbox tiles if you tell it to do so. Just take a look at the [readme](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image#leaflet-image).

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't notice. However, it's too beta to be usable at the moment. When I pan around on the demo page sometimes it will stop rendering new tiles. And when I tried to use the map from the leafletjs main page it wouldn't render any tiles at all. Once it works I think it will solve my problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [leaflet-image](http://mapbox.github.io/leaflet-image/). leaflet-image can generate image dataURLs from [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/) L.map objects using [OSM tiles](http://mapbox.github.io/leaflet-image/osm.html). It uses CORS to request the tiles and avoid [tainting the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image#What_is_a_.22tainted.22_canvas.3F).

Thanks to @tyr for mentioning leaflet-image in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939115/generating-redistributable-map-images-without-a-server#comment27977238_18939115). The issues I mentioned in the comments have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We developed a solution using TileMill to generate MBTiles files. We then developed a very simple PHP script, which opened the MBTiles (essentially a sqlite db) then saved the blobs for each image out to a file.